# Android - Toolbar popup custom layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, popup, toolbar

Was wondering how you would go about implementing a custom layout for a toolbar popup, the one you get when you press on the settings button.
I need to increase the padding on the top and bottom of the popup, and also add in a custom font here. The only way I can think to do it would be to basically inflate a custom layout here but I'm not sure how it can be done. Most of the documentation I find online about it is just about styling it instead of adding in a new layout.

I thought maybe doing something like:

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_settings_popup"
```

Would work, but unfortunately it doesn't. Also trying to set the layout and background in styles didn't
Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be what you need:
https://scriptedpapers.com/2015/02/12/android-action-bar-and-overflow-menu-customization-with-theme-appcompat/

Comment: Is that not just changing the color and stuff? What about if I need a custom font? I would need to create a custom View for it no?

Comment: If you need to change font, try using one of the libraries, that attach to the context and changes all `TextView`'s font automatically, ie. [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)